# What is messing with the logging in AsyncWebsocketConsumer?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have a Django project that's using Channels for websocket communication and I've stumbled upon what I think might be a bug, but I'm not certain so I'm hoping someone that understands this better than I do can help explain what's happening here:

Test error message:

```
AssertionError: "INFO:websocket.camera_consumer:Doesn't work" not found in ['INFO:websocket.camera_consumer:Works']
```

Test that's failing:

```py
class TestCameraConsumerTests(TransactionTestCase):
    async def test_fails(self):
        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(TestConsumer.as_asgi(), '/ws/device')

        with self.assertLogs(f'websocket.camera_consumer', level=logging.INFO) as logs:
            await communicator.connect(timeout=10)

        await communicator.disconnect()
        self.assertIn(f"INFO:websocket.camera_consumer:Doesn't work", logs.output)
```

`websocket.camera_consumer.py`:

```py
import logging
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

def sync_function():
    pass

class TestConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await super().connect()

        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        logger.info("Works")
        await sync_to_async(sync_function)()
        logger.info("Doesn't work")
```

What I've learned so far:

- Moving the getLogger call outside the `connect` function doesn't fix it
- Moving the `super` call below the `sync_to_async` call **does** fix it
- Removing the `sync_to_async` function (and making `sync_function` async) **also** fixes it
- Somewhere along the way in the `sync_to_async` function call, the logger handler object that the `assertLogs` injects gets removed so the first log message gets routed to the test, but the second log message does not
- I've attempted to step-though the sync_to_async call, however I can't figure out how to monitor the logger object while inside the async loop (I'm still relatively new-ish to async code so not super well versed in how it works under the hood).